# MongoDB Aggregate, Arrays and Logical Operations

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, logical-operators, intersection

I'm trying to do operations between 2 arrays with MongoDB Aggregate.

Let's say first array is

```
files = [["1.txt", "2.txt", "4.txt"], [ "1.txt", "2.txt"],  [ "1.txt" ]].
```

And the other one is

```
operators = ["=",  "+"]
```

How can I write a code that takes the first 2 elements from files and one from operators (let's say you bound "+" to $setIntersection and "=" to $setUnion) and do the operation required. This shall be repeated until there are no more operators(the result of the last operation with a new element of files). How can this be achieved in MongoDB with aggregate or other methods?

I tried, I really tried and got this:

```
.aggregate([{"$match": {"term":{"$in":["1", "10", "100"]}}},
            {"$group": {"_id":"BooleanSearch","files": { "$push": "$docs.d" },"initialSet": { "$first": "$docs.d" }}},
            {"$addFields":{"operators":["=", "+"]}},
            {"$unwind":"$operators"},
            {"$addFields": {"result": {"$reduce": {"input": "$files", "initialValue": "$initialSet" ,"in": {"$switch":{"branches": [
                     { case: {"$eq": [ "$operators", "+"]}, then: { "$setIntersection": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]}},
                     { case: {"$eq": [ "$operators", "-"]}, then: { "$setDifference": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]}},
                     { case: {"$eq": [ "$operators", "="]}, then: { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]}}],
                     default: "Index out of bounds"}}}}}},
            {"$project":{"_id":0,"result":1}}])
```

This produces this output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        "1.txt", 
        "2.txt", 
        "4.txt"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        "1.txt"
    ]
}
```

What all of this does is: for each operator you do the operation to all the array, which is not what I intended, and that brings you the result(all the array with the same operation). How can one work with the elements of the array not with the whole array?

The desired result would be

```
{ "result" : [ "1.txt" ] }
```

It is obtain by union(=) between the first 2 elements of files, followed up by intersection(+) of the result with the last element of files.

Comment: Can you post please the desired result?

Comment: The desired result would be `{
    "result" : [ 
        "1.txt"
    ]
} `. It is obtain by union(=) between the first 2 elements of files, followed up by intersection(+) of the result with the last element of files.